# Listing members that are not from parent class

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

How can I list the members of a control (say `TrackBar` or `ListBox`) that were not inherited from the parent class and belong to the Control's own implementation. I have tried Object Browser, Properties Window and the Code Editor itself, but all of them list all the members.

This kind of info can be useful in a number of scenarios. One example is my case, where I'm implementing a `ToolStripControlHost` for `TrackBar` control and want to see which members of the `TrackBar` I'd need to add to my class.

**UPDATE:** Inspired by @Aaronaught's second suggestion below, I spent some time trying to create a VS2010 add-in that listens to cursor position change event, but it seems to be too much for the poor programmer in me.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.aspx) would help. It specifies which members are inherited.

If you need to do this through code (Reflection), specify `DeclaredOnly` in the [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) of [Type.GetMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmembers.aspx).

Comment: Given my requirement, I'm more inclined towards an IDE-based solution. MSDN lists ALL the members again, just like the other 3 methods I mentioned in the question, so that won't help much. Reflection seems to be an option. I should probably create a Visual Studio extension that lists the members of the identifier around the cursor.

Comment: @dotNET: Please read MSDN more carefully. It says which members are inherited. I really can't see why you'd need to be able to do this within Visual Studio, but not programmatically... maybe you should provide more information about the problem you're trying to solve, there's probably another/better way.

Comment: Thanks. I may not have been clear enough. Going through MSDN for class members is time-consuming, becuz the average framework class would have several dozen members. And I have no problem doing if this could be achieved programmatically; only that an IDE-based solution would readily list all local members of the identifier under cursor, so I won't have to pass it to a macro or something for each type manually. A VS addin is best suitable for this becuz not only it is "programmatic", it also allows me to create a docking window that would update on the fly, though I couldn't build one.

Comment: *Why* could you possibly need this information within Visual Studio? It really sounds like you're going way off the rails with something. I guess you could do it a little quicker by navigating to the class definition and checking for non-override members? Use Reflector or ILSpy? I just can't help thinking that if this were actually something important to be able to do, you wouldn't be the first person asking.

Comment: There was a way to do this in Visual Studio some time in the past, when "Go To Definition" command used to extract class declarations from metadata and open them in a new code editor window (having the string "[from metadata]" in the title, if u recall). That is no longer an option in VS2010. Going to definition now options the class in Object Browser :(. Anyway, I guess we have spent more time on it than it was worth. Thanks for your prolonged contribution.